# query for a few hundred .db SQLite databases

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have been asked to create a simple program to submit user defined queries to SQLite databases (.db). I have not worked with the offline databases before and have a question about optimizing performance.

There are a few hundred .db files that I need to query. Is it quicker to attach them all to a single query using ATTACH, or join them all into a single database and work from there? My thoughts are that there will be some trade off between how much time it takes for inital set up versus the query speed. Is there perhaps a different method that would result in better performance?

I dont think it will matter, but this will be written with C# for a windows OS desktop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_attached) says:

> The number of simultaneously attached databases is limited to SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED which is set to 10 by default. [...] The number of attached databases cannot be increased above 62.

So attaching a few hundred databases will be *very* quick because outputting an error message can be done *really fast*. ☺

Comment: @ C.L. Thanks, I must have missed that! Is there really no better solution that repeating the query for every set of 62 databases? Maybe an initial merge to create one DB would be better. They are all typed the same.

Comment: It doesn't look as if you have a choice.